# Could not establish trust relationship with remote server

Tags: c#, web-services

Unable to download file from https://www.test.com/AssemblyDepot/v1.1/version600/1.1.3173.36029/xxx600.dll to C:\Program Files\Gateway\bin\xxx600.dll --> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship with remote server.

Please any help me to resolve this issue,

Thanks in advance,

Pradeep

Comment: If you can share some code for downloading the file, it would help to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely the hostname in the server certificate does not match the hostname used in the URL.
Other reasons include:

- the certificate is not from a trusted issuer
- the certificate has expired.

Comment: here we have two servers one is 'test' server other is 'Gateway' server, where the host name is having problem.

Comment: But did you check the certificates as I have advised? SSL relies on certificates to secure the communications. That is why they must pass several checks to be accepted.